# How does value of query.connector set in Q objects in Django code?

Tags: python, django

During django websie development I came across of django Q objects & query.

I have below code like.

I have referred official documentation from 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/.

```
 query = Q()
    if request.POST.get('emp_name') != None:
        query.add(Q(emp_name__icontains=str(request.POST.get('emp_name'))), query.connector)
```

I know how Query Q objects works but not able to understand how query.connector value defined.

query.connector value will be like 'AND' , 'OR' likewise.

I am not able to get any online references for above kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: If you do not pass a `_connector` yourself. Django will end up using **`'AND'`** as a connector.

A `Q` object is a subclass of `tree.Node`. Indeed we can inspect the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/db/models/query_utils.py#L47-L59):

> ```
> class Q(tree.Node):
>     """
>     Encapsulate filters as objects that can then be combined logically (using
>     `&` and `|`).
>     """
>     # Connection types
>     AND = 'AND'
>     OR = 'OR'
>     default = AND
>     conditional = True
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, _connector=None, _negated=False, **kwargs):
>         super().__init__(children=[*args, *sorted(kwargs.items())], connector=_connector, negated=_negated)
>
>     # …
> ```

When we thus construct a `Q` object, we make a super call to the `tree.Node` data constructor, and if we do not pass a `_connector`, it will take `None` as value.

The `Node` itself will however take the default in case the truthiness of the `connector` is `None`. Indeed, if we look at the [source code of **`Node`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/tree.py#L11-L25), we see:

> ```
> class Node:
>     """
>     A single internal node in the tree graph. A Node should be viewed as a
>     connection (the root) with the children being either leaf nodes or other
>     Node instances.
>     """
>     # Standard connector type. Clients usually won't use this at all and
>     # subclasses will usually override the value.
>     default = 'DEFAULT'
>
>     def __init__(self, children=None, connector=None, negated=False):
>         """Construct a new Node. If no connector is given, use the default."""
>         self.children = children[:] if children else []
>         self.connector = connector or self.default
>         self.negated = negated
>
>     # …
> ```

This thus means that if you construct a `Q` object, the default connector is the value of `Q.AND` and thus `'AND'`.

Comment: I got it. Superb !